# List videos with a given word

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As you know, youtube has a property that there are subtitles of videos with soft-coded. By clicking `cc` it can be seen. There is also a website helping a guy to learn pronounciation of a english word, [www.youglish.com](https://youglish.com/search/opportunity/us?)

The website searches subtitled videos a given word and brings the part of it with the word said. That is, it is able to search videos by subtitle. What is the way/method/step(s) to do that? Besides, ibm has a work similar [that](https://support.video.ibm.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000016309-Search-in-Video-How-to-search-for-any-spoken-word-in-a-video)

Comment: For what I had checked in the responses each time I make a search by word in the website you provided *(i.e. youglish.com)*, I can't tell for sure how they do that, but I think they have a database with specified videos that matches with the given word. I can add answer with a idea about how you can do that, but I don't know whether this might be considered off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=en) for request videos that:

- has `closed caption`.
- matches with the search terms.

In this example, this is the `search.list` request for search videos with `closecaption` enabled and that matches with the search term ***(charming)***:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=4&q=charming&type=video&videoCaption=closedCaption&fields=items(id(channelId%2Ckind%2CvideoId)%2Ckind%2Csnippet(channelTitle%2Cdescription%2Ctitle))&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

[Demo available in Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=4&q=charming&type=video&videoCaption=closedCaption&fields=items(id(channelId%252Ckind%252CvideoId)%252Ckind%252Csnippet(channelTitle%252Cdescription%252Ctitle))&_h=1&):

These are the results:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "ztsbgEUzVpc"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "CHARMING Official Trailer (2018) Demi Lovato, Sia, Animation Movie HD",
    "description": "CHARMING Official Trailer © 2018 - Smith Global Media Comedy, Kids, Family and Animated Film, Blockbuster, Action Cinema, Blockbuster, Scifi Movie or ...",
    "channelTitle": "ONE Media"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "sO5F8DulPPk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "How to be more Charismatic - 6 Charisma Tips to be more Charming and Attractive",
    "description": "Use my FREE 27 Confidence-Boosting Hacks: https://practicalpie.com/confidence/ Want my TOP 10 book list?: https://practicalpie.com/book-list/ Get a girl to like ...",
    "channelTitle": "Practical Psychology"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "gesBAZo2_l4"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "9 Tricks to Be the Most Charming Person in the Room",
    "description": "How to be a bit more charming? Some people could easily gain the trust of everyone and create a positive image of themselves? Jeff Haden, one of the most ...",
    "channelTitle": "BRIGHT SIDE"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "wMVPU3uUc5g"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "title": "10 Signs You Are An Exceptionally Charming Person",
    "description": "If you have these signs you are an exceptionally charming person – even if you don't think you are! Charm is the power or quality of delighting, attracting or ...",
    "channelTitle": "BRAINY DOSE"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Unfortunately, not all returned videos has *(in is captions)* the given word - in this case, the word: **charming**.

Hence, you have to loop the videos returned in the `search.list` response and select the one who has indeed the given word.

Next, you can get the captions by passing the `videoId`:

You can use this URL for get the captions:

```
https://video.google.com/timedtext?type=track&v=<VIDEO_ID>&id=0&lang=en
```

The working jsfiddle for retrieve the captions by modifying the URl and add the `videoId` is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSOes/yu19knrL/).